# Javascript result of anonymous function in or

Tags: javascript

is it possible to get the result of an anonymous function like so:

```
myarray[myelement] = myarray[myelement] || function() { return "result" };
```

Basically i want to assign the value of the function if the array element does not exist

Comment: Just don’t put your function inline. It’s cleaner that way. =)

Comment: Sorry, i changed question.

Comment: I'd go for an IIFE, just calling the function would give me the willies, even if I can't really come up with a reason why ?

Comment: Personally, I'd say that you're just making code that is hard to read and hard to follow.  Write a couple more lines of code and use an `if` statement and your code will be much cleaner.  This one line trick is fine when things are simple (e.g. value `a` or `b`, but when you're talking about an inline function call with logic in it, why make the code less readable just to save a line or two.  In order, I prioritize: Correctness, Readability, Maintainability then Brevity and it pays off in the long run.

Comment: Granted i am still very new to javascript, but im working on something very similar to this: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/ in particular you can see the line cache[str] = cache[str] || ... I would have thought John Resig would be a trustworthy source for learning from

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Invoke the function using `()`:

```
myarray[myelement] = myarray[myelement] || function() { return "result" }();
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Lbgk7/